# python counting and appending to list

Tags: python

I'm trying to count how times something occurs in a list.  Is it possible to set a variable to move through each index and count it.  I want to append how many times each one is counter to a list.
I want it to look like this.  Forget the while loop, it's just to show that I'm looping this. 
example.  And if possible to to import a library to make a shortcut, or if its the only way.

```
while True:
    index = 0
    L = ["brown", "brown", "brown", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow"]
    numberOfTimes = L.count([index]) 
    index = index + numberOfTimes 
    numberOfTimesList.append(numberOfTimes)
```

I'd then want to make another list and so that I'd only see brown once like this:

```
["brown", "red", "yellow"] [3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`collections.counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter
L = ["brown", "brown", "brown", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow"]
cnt = Counter(L)
print cnt
print cnt.keys(), cnt.values()
```

Output:

```
Counter({'brown': 3, 'yellow': 2, 'red': 2})
['brown', 'yellow', 'red'] [3, 2, 2]
```

The resulting counter object can be manipulated as a dictionary, with additional convenient routines such as `cnt.most_common(n)` which will return the `n` most common elements and their counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1].count(1)
```

The above code counts the number of times the number `1` appears in the list. You can do the same for your list.

In your case do this.

```
for thing in L:
  # Count variable represents the number of times the thing variable was found
  count = L.count(thing)
```

Comment: `count` is good when you want to count the occurrences of one thing, but when you want to count all the items, it suffers quadratic runtime compared to `collections.Counter`'s linear performance.

Comment: @user2357112 that is so true.

Answer (score 0):

To the basic of Python:

First, a `Pythonic` way for loop or iteration is:

```
In [5]: L = ["brown", "brown", "brown", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow"]

In [6]: for i in L:
   ...:     print i
   ...:     
brown
brown
brown
red
red
yellow
yellow
```

Second, to count the occurrence, the most basic and powerful tool in Python: [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) will help.

```
In [8]: counts = {}

In [9]: for i in L:
   ...:     counts[i] = (counts[i] + 1) if (i in counts) else 1
   ...:     

In [10]: counts
Out[10]: {'brown': 3, 'red': 2, 'yellow': 2}

In [11]: counts.keys()
Out[11]: ['brown', 'yellow', 'red']

In [12]: counts.values()
Out[12]: [3, 2, 2]
```

Using `collections.Counter` as @YS-L said is more convince for your question, but I think it would be better to be familiar with basic of Python before useing a tool of higher level

Comment: Don't use `and`/`or` to simulate [conditional expressions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/). The `and`/`or` hack is bug-prone and unnecessary.

Comment: A step further is to use ``counts = collections.defaultdict(int)``, before delegating everything to ``collections.Counter``.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks! Answer corrected. I knew the `and/or` is bug-prone, such when should return `0` for true and `1` for false. But I didn't know the `Conditional Expressions` at all :(